# request.respone returns 'None' although the response is not actually empty empty (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using continuous request capture with a URL filter to capture all the requests that load through a webpage to achieve this I am using selenium-wire interceptors , here is my code:

```
def interceptor(request):
    if 'URL' in request.url:
        print(request.response)




def main():
    driver.request_interceptor = interceptor
    driver.get(SITE_URL)
    for request in driver.requests:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") #Scrolls the webpage so more requests load...
        time.sleep(3)
main()
```

Problem is the interceptor function prints 'None' although the response from the request [is not empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFf1u.jpg)? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to check first the type of the request you're passing as an argument and check if its contains stuffs

Comment: @Sanixdarker You mean if it's a GET or POST etc. request?

Comment: @Sanixdarker it's a GET request, matches the one from the image..